# Raycast hit dont work properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have written a code to change the color of a object by selecting it

```
void Update () {
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); 
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit, 1000.0f) && Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0))
        {
            if(hit.collider.gameObject == this.gameObject)
            {
                Debug.Log("Wall Clicked");

                mgr.clickedWall=gameObject;

        }
        else if(Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit, 1000.0f) && Input.GetMouseButtonDown (1)) 
        {

            hit.collider.gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.red;

        }
    }
```

it works fine when main camera is on the initial position but when the camera
position changes color changes but not on the object that I clicked.what is the isuue over here.

Comment: Try with Debug.DrawRay() to see how your ray looks like, https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html

Comment: you will need to elaborate a bit more about your problem. Its very vague. Which object is being affected after camera change? whose color changes ? And Dont use raycast in update rather put the raycast in flag check like if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown (value)) { Raycast code}. Also your closing bracket is missing in second if... im assuming its typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like your whole logic is wrong. Thy out something like this. please note that this is attached to the camera and not the gameobject you are clicking. I think your problem stems from doing the raycast in a if that also checks if a mouse button is down.

```
 void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Test")
                {
                    Debug.Log("Wall Clcked");
                }
            }

        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
            }

        }
    }
```